# launch failed . binary not found in eclipse europa

Tags: eclipse, mingw, eclipse-cdt

```
*** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\first.o ..\src\first.cpp
Internal Builder: Exec error:Launching failed
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 62  ms.
```

I am getting the above error in eclipse console when I  tried to build my first "hello world" CPP program. Below are the steps I followed.

1. Installed Eclipse Europa.
2. Installed MinGW.
3. Open Eclipse goto window->preferences->c/C++->NEW CDT project wizard-> changed the Tool chain as "MinGW GCC".
4. When I opened the eclipse workspace manually there is  no exe generated for the program.
5. My PATH variable in the project properties has "C:\MinGW" as value.

I searched much in net and still this "Launch Failed No Binaries" did not go off.
Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Launch failed No Binaries" means the program is not compiled.So this is the problem
related with MinGW GCC.Check you gave all the environmental variables necessary for the MINGW
correctly.
MoreOver I Suggest CodeBlocks IDE as a replacement.It is much Better than eclipse for c++
The link is [CodeBlocks Download Link](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26)